# jQuery Mobile dropdown menu bug in iOS

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-mobile

I have got bug reports on a jQuery Mobile project beta 2 project with dropdown menu (select tags in html) that says when the scroll the wheel on the native "select value" in a dropdown menu its zooming the page and when selected a value its not being set back, the user need to tap to get normal zoom again.

I only has Android to test on, is there someone else that got the same problem and have a solution for it or is it a bug in iOS or jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I use jQueryMobile in 2 big projects, I never had a complain and using iOS everyday, I never got that problem.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem myself.  Did some googling, and the solution is to put

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

the maximum-scale=1 will solve your issue, but it will also not allow the user to zoom in or out, which may or may not be acceptable for your situation.