# HTML Select Tag issue on iOS

Tags: iphone, html, select

I have created a Simple HTML page with a label and a Select tag field. Code for the same is as follows:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<label>Interval</label>
<select name="interval" id="Interval">
<option value="1hr">1 hour</option>
<option value="2hr">2 hour</option>
<option value="1dy">1 day</option>
<option value="2dy">2 day</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Now as I run this HTML page on iPhone, iPod (iOS), on click of the drop list, the size of the label (instead whole HTML page gets broader, gets increased).

I am unable to understand the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have added the HTML tag to your question as that is the more important tag here - just tagging it iPhone will typically bring it to the attention of iOS developers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in iOS4.  It stays zoomed in after selection.  iOS5 supposedly has this fixed.

Comment: You could try the suggestion in the last comment here--> https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2069

Comment: Is there any documentation where I can find more details related to this bug?

Comment: Just other [commentary]  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117946/jquery-mobile-dropdown-menu-bug-in-ios) at the moment, but I will look around.